# Git push URL encoding issue

Tags: git, github

I have a use case to push files to git using command like:

```
git push https://<username>:<password>github.company.com/abcd/devrepo master:master
```

But, if the password contains special characters like ‘@’ and ‘$’, I am converting it to hex code like ‘%40’ and %24.

So, the URL looks like -

```
https://23784:Abcd%40%241234@github.company.com/abcd/devrepo
```

I was thinking it should work since I am encoding the special character, but it throws 403 error everytime. This works fine for password without special characters where we don’t need to encode any characters.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use SSH?

Comment: This is a service consumed by many users and there is a validation requirement where every user trying to use this service, needs to be authenticated against the repo that is passed. For ex: User '23784' needs to be authenticated against https://github.company.com/abcd/devrepo URL before allowing to proceed further. This works with GitHub access tokens and even with passwords without special characters. Just trying to see if there is a way to make it work with encoded password.